# Playing sound in c# more efficient

Tags: c#, audio

I programmed in C# a winning wheel. For each field it plays a sound. From 200 ms up to 1,5 seconds. (Sounds like a "tick").

This is my code (only sound):

```
public class Global{
    public static WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer tick_sound = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();  
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e){
    Global.tick_sound.controls.stop();
    Global.tick_sound.URL = @"\Resources\tick.mp3";
    Global.tick_sound.controls.play();
}
```

It's working, but the sound doesn't sound really good in this timerloop. I guess Windows Media Player is to slow. Is there any other way to play sounds and play that faster and better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NAudio is a good alternative. You can get it here:
http://naudio.codeplex.com/

Install NAudio.
Add NAudio, and NAudio.Wave, as a referance in your project.
And use it's code.

Here's an Example:

```
class PlaySound
{
    IWavePlayer wave;
    AudioFileReader file;



    public PlaySound(string FILE)
    {
       file = new AudioFileReader(FILE);
       wave = new WaveOut();
    }

    public void playSound()
    {
         wave.Init();
         wave.Play();
    }
}
```

And then in your code that plays sound:

```
PlaySound sound = new PlaySound(@"\Resources\tick.mp3");
sound.playSound();
```